# Offset/Fetch based paging (Implementation) in EntityFramework (Using LINQ) for SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, sql-server-2008, pagination, entity-framework-6

I am using SQL Server 2008 and Entity Framework 6.1.3. I wish to implement pagination of data based on OFFSET/FETCH rather than Take() & Skip().

I searched online with no luck. Some posts suggested migrating to SQL Server 2012. Which is not an option in my case.

Can someone suggest how to use OFFSET/FETCH with SQL Server 2008 and EF 6.1.3

Comment: SQL Server 2008 does ot support the OFFSET / FECTH syntax

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is possible with [Entity Framework 6.1.2](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/961) and above so you should be OK to use it in your project. The standard Skip and Take methods can't be captured in the same way as others. There are now two additional overload of the Skip/Take methods that take lambdas, so instead of this:

```csharp
var results = context.MyTable
    .Skip(10)
    .Take(5);
```

Do this:

```csharp
var results = context.MyTable
    .Skip(() => 10)
    .Take(() => 5);
```

Comment: Thanks David, I saw your response above in the comments, but now with this answer I think it makes sense now.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I still get 

Incorrect syntax near 'OFFSET'.
Invalid usage of the option NEXT in the FETCH statement.

`var list = q.OrderBy(orderBy).Skip(() => skip).Take(() => pageSize).ToList();`

get's translated to

`ORDER BY row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Project1].[PRIORITY] ASC, [Project1].[CREATED] ASC)
    OFFSET @p__linq__1 ROWS FETCH NEXT @p__linq__2 ROWS ONLY ',N'@p__linq__0 varchar(8000),@p__linq__1 int,@p__linq__2 int',@p__linq__0='STS_NEW',@p__linq__1=0,@p__linq__2=12`

the same code normally works on SQL 2012 and above

Comment: @DavidG Why use the lambdas? What's the advantage?

Comment: @orangecaterpillar IF you read the question and answer, you will see the different SQL that is generated.

Comment: @DavidG I don't see SQL in the question or answer.

Answer (score 5):

The fix is to modify your EDMX file, using the XML editor, and change the value of ProviderManifestToken from 2012 to 2008. I found that on line 7 in my EDMX file. After saving that change, the paging SQL will be generated using the “old”, SQL Server 2008 compatible syntax.

Comment: This one solved my issue! Thanks man. It worked on SQL Server 2008, without changing anything in my linq code.

Answer (score -2):

This example may helps you to use OffSET In Sql server

```
DECLARE @PageNo INT=NULL, 
@RowsPerPage INT=2
;WIth cte(id, name, qty, price)
AS
(
SELECT 2,'a', 2, 20 UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'d', 2, 10 UNION ALL
SELECT 4,'b', 3, 60
)
,cte2 AS (SELECT id, name, qty, price , 1 AS n FROM cte
UNION ALL
SELECT id, name, qty, price , n+1 From cte2 t
WHERE n< t.qty
)
SELECT
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1) ) AS Seq,
  id,
  name,
  qty,
  price
FROM cte2
ORDER BY 2, 3, n

OFFSET (COALESCE((CASE  WHEN @PageNo <= 0 THEN 1
                        WHEN @PageNo > 0 THEN @PageNo END), 1) - 1) ROWS
FETCH NEXT @RowsPerPage ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort @Srini131, However I am looking for something in EF using LINQ