# SQL Server 2008 Skip Take with long parameter

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, sql-server-2008-r2

This question is very likely to this question (so need to implement pagination with SQL Server 2008 and Entity Framework):

[Offset/Fetch based paging (Implementation) in EntityFramework (Using LINQ) for SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45302539/offset-fetch-based-paging-implementation-in-entityframework-using-linq-for-s)

However the problem is that my DB have more than 10 billion rows. So basically `Skip` does not work, I need a `Skip/Take` methods that accept "long" as parameter. Any possible solution with Linq and EF? Thanks

Comment: I would suggest to pre-filter the records to avoid the usage of long parameters. In my opinion it's a bit senseless if you need `long`'s number range for paging - I think the usage of `Skip` or `Take` should never be over `Int32` range record count.

Comment: Somehow I doubt you're going to be selecting more than 2 billion rows in a single query. Just because your table is big does not mean your pagination should be.

Comment: @JeroenMostert But the problem is his design might involve skipping more than 2 billion rows to take 20 (!).

Comment: I Agree @ChW but those methods are the only way to do paging in EF, it is EF that should not implement paging with something that is not capable of using "long" in first place. I agree, my paginations are small, but netherless the only way to do paging is to order by something and Skip Take with EF. If I need to Skip something like 8 billions, than return 100 records than I'm in trouble. SQL is able to do that. It is just a limit imposed by EF that I was not aware of.. No workarounds then?

Comment: Is your data sorted and if so, wich criteria do you use? Ordered by ID or is it possible to order by ID only?

Comment: EF has little choice. There is no way to do fast general pagination in SQL, if it has to be exact. `OFFSET` and `FETCH` do not change this -- yes, you can use an offset greater than 2 billion with that, but it's not going to be actually usable, as it will have to skip the exact number of rows you specify, and it can't use a seek for this. Rather than allow you to use such huge offsets, it makes more sense to have you rethink the way you do pagination, as this would be necessary even if you used pure SQL.

Comment: So your page size is 100. That means the user is going to have to skip 21 million pages before they run into a problem with int32.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if it is necessary at all - expected the case in comments where you have to skip billions to take only 20 - to read as lot as possible data.

- You could use a stored procedure that will get the amount to skip and
  take.
- Another approach would be to execute a plain SQL on your dbContext's database property.

If you want to use LINQ and you have increment IDs you could give following a try - but it is a bit more expensive and it will not cover the long value for data amount to retrieve:

At first execution you have to determine the ID of `int.MaxValue`-1. After that point you could re-use the logic for rest of paging. (maybe depending on a flag)
Use the ID as where clause (lower border) and add a `Take` with needed amount. From result's last record you will save the ID for next paging call where you will use it instead of first determined ID.

A possible approach code (*not tested*) could be (will not cover all your cases without any modifications):

```
private long _lastId;

public IEnumerable<Students> GetPage(int toTake)
{
    List<Students> result;

    result = isFirstPage
        ? _context.Students
            .Take(toTake)
            .ToList();
        : _context.Students
            .Where(s => s.Id > _lastId)
            .Take(toTake)
            .ToList();

    _lastId = result.LastOrDefault()?.Id ?? 0;


    return result;
}
```