# What does the code query.Take(() => 1) do?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I ran across the following code while maintaining a project `query.Take(() => 1)`.

`query` is of type `IQueryable<T>`.

What does passing a lambda do differently than passing an `int`?

**edit**: Edit to clarify that I'm not asking about `FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: @Sinatr See here for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45302539/offset-fetch-based-paging-implementation-in-entityframework-using-linq-for-s/45303019#45303019

Comment: @DavidG Shouldn´t the documentation of that method answer this question then? If so, where is it?

Comment: @HimBromBeere The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dn344948(v=vs.113)) don't answer the difference between `Take` and `FirstOrDefault` though

Comment: @DavidG But shouldn´t it mention the difference between `Take(int)` and `Take(Func<int>)`? Otherwise there´s little use, for that extension, IMHO.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Possibly, but that's not what OP is asking

Comment: Where is `Take` comming from? The `System.Linq.Enumerable` class has no overload of it taking a func. But `TakeWhile` has. It accepts a `Func<bool>`. The same is true for `Queryable`.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dn344948(v=vs.113)

Comment: Read the docs. It can take `Expression<Func<Int32>>`. In this case, it's `() => 1`

Comment: @Ergis These docs belong to an extension, so its not an obvious place to look for (its not a standard Queryable extension).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a few things to explain here.

1. `query.Take(() => 1` ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.queryableextensions.take?view=entity-framework-6.2.0))

   This returns an `IQueryable<T>` which may contain a single item. It will run a query that uses the SQL Server `TOP` syntax which means it will work on SQL Server 2008 and earlier.
2. `query.Take(1)`

   This is similar to the previous version, but it uses the newer SQL Server `OFFSET`/`FETCH` syntax and is the preferred method unless you need legacy support.
3. `query.FirstOrDefault()`

   This will return a single instance of your entity, or a null if there are no matches. If you want a single item, this is usually the preferred method. You will need to check for null in your code though.

will return an enumerable whereas `query.FirstOrDefault` will give you a single item, or null. They will run very different

Comment: I got a -1 in my answer down below when I think it is correct. Was it you, by any means? Bcause im really frustrated by the lack of professionalism in here

Comment: @Ergis Not me sorry, though someone has also downvoted this one

Comment: Just wonder, what is the use case of the lambda not just returning a constant?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Returning a constant?

Comment: @DavidG `() => 1` I mean the `1` its returning. From the API point of view we would just call `.Take(1)`

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Oh, it's not returning that, that's why I was confused. Does my answer not explain the difference enough?

Comment: Yes it is, but introducing a pretty non-sensical lambda just to create another overload of `Take`? A `.Fetch(int)` would be much clearer.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes No, that's the wrong way round, that would mean they should have  added a `.Top(int)` method. I don't think there's a great way to solve this problem, and really there should be virtually no one using the lambda version any more, that database tech is 12 years old now - it's time to upgrade!

Comment: Can the lambda be used to create a sub-query or a call to a stored function? Because then it would be meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

The code writer should have written documentation of that line.

But if you use MSFT documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.queryableextensions.take?view=entity-framework-6.2.0

```
public static System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource> Take<TSource> (this System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource> source, 
    System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<int>> countAccessor);
```

`countAccessor  Expression<Func<Int32>>`

An expression that evaluates to the number of elements to return.